# Compare java getTime time with strings representing a date

Tags: java, android

I have stored the date of a specific method each time it gets executed in ab sqlite database in 3 columns (one for the day, the month and the year).

Now I want to compare it to the date  of the actutal day the user uses the app. With

`Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`

I get this date, but how am I able to compare it to the strings I get from my database? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the classic way will help: convert all dates to milliseconds and then compare each other.

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-simpledateformat and use this simpledateformat for format and parse

Comment: IMO You should use timestamp to store date in database.

Comment: @SagarGangwal this sounds useful I'll take a try on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
String strDate= formattedDate.format(date);
```

It will give you your date as shown in the Template. Now simply build a String out of your SQLite data in the same way (dd/MM/yyyy) and you cam simply compare them like shown in this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java](http://click%20me)

Comment: Use `yyyy/MM/dd` if you want to compare dates as strings.

Answer (score 1):

## Using java.time

Your Question is a duplicate of many others. So briefly…

Use java.time classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. For Android, use libraries from the ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects.

Get today’s date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Get to parts of the date.

```
int y = today.getYear() ;
int m = today.getMonthValue() ;
int d = today.getDayOfMonth() ;
```

Query the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setInt( 1 , y ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setInt( 2 , m ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setInt( 3 , d ) ;
```

As others suggested, you should be using date-time types in your database to store date-time values rather than mere ints for the pieces.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).